# heroku postgresql database rails app PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "comments" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i was run:

```
git push heroku master
heroku bin/rails db:migrate
```

ignore success create tables (date too much), just show error part.

```
== 20161127134205 AddArticleIdToComment: migrating ============================
-- add_column(:comments, :article_id, :integer)
D, [2016-12-29T11:14:54.118466 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.1ms)  ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "article_id" integer
D, [2016-12-29T11:14:54.123821 #4] DEBUG -- :    (5.0ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-12-29T11:14:54.127986 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.7ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(4403768336151726570)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "comments" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "article_id" integer
```

run `heroku run rails c` -> `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` show:

```
=> ["schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata", "users", "articles"]
```

but run `Comment.connection` unbelievable could connection and run `Comment` show

```
=> Comment(Table doesn't exist)
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'searchkick', '~> 1.4'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161225092307) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "node_id"
    t.string   "article_img_file_name"
    t.string   "article_img_content_type"
    t.integer  "article_img_file_size"
    t.datetime "article_img_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.integer  "raty"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "nodes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "nodeName"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "suggestions_texts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

table association:

Article:

```
  class Article < ApplicationRecord

  searchkick
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :node
  has_attached_file :article_img, styles: { index_img: "300x300>", show_img: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :article_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Comments:

```
   class Comment < ApplicationRecord

      belongs_to :article
      belongs_to :user
   end
```

problem is: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "comments" does not exist`

have some way would solve ?

thanks

Comment: what is the issue ?? Model association or `db:migrate` not running on heroku ??

Comment: oh, run: `heroku run bin/rails db:migrate` occur this isssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holla. 
It's basically simple question. 
You trying to run AddArticleIdToComment migration, which expect comments table to be created before. 
Have you create a table? 
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` shows that no.

If you have migration that create a table, please run

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

to ensure that migration was migrated. 
If you have no one - please add it. I do see table in your schemma, so hope you have one. 
You need to run first

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
        ....
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ```class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        create_table :comments do |t|
          t.integer :raty
          t.text :body

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end```

Comment: @F___, your migration looks good. So, did you run/create this migration BEFORE AddArticleIdToComment migration?
see - every time you run rails g migration it creates you file with timestamp, and then rails use this timestamp to run migrations in correct order. thats why migration name looks like db/migrate/20151113091525_create_users.rb. so make sure your migration is in right order based on filenames. again -  rake db:migrate:status to ensure that migration was UP